# Is my HTTP protocol design correctly implemented in the coding?

Tags: java, http, file-io, http-headers, client-server

It's my very simple client-server application. Client sends some commands to the server and server gives back the output to the client. However, my special concern is about the `GET` command sent to the server. The client request `GET filename` to download a named file. That file ultimately gets downloaded into the client directory with the HTTP response headers, as I have designed my protocol.

Now I am afraid if my coding follows the protocol accurately. Especially the HTTP response headers with the Line break (in both client and server side).

PROTOCOL DESIGN:

Client:

```
syntax: GET  namedfile CRLF
CRLF
meaning: downloading the named file from the server
representation: text file
```

server:

```
syntax: Status: ok CRLF
Length: 20 bytes CRLF
CRLF
File contents
meaning: The file exist in the server and ready to 
download
representation: text file
```

CODE:

ServerSide:

```
                          .................
                          .................
else if (request.startsWith("GET")) {
                        System.out.println("");
                        String filename = request.substring(4);
                        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                        File[] files = file.listFiles();

                        if (fileExists(files, filename)) {
                            file = new File(filename);
                            int fileSize = (int) file.length();
                            outputToClient.print("Status OK\r\n"
                                    + "Size " + fileSize + "KB" + "\r\n"
                                    + "\r\n"
                                    + "File " + filename + " Download was successfully\r\n");
                            outputToClient.flush();
                            // reading files
                            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                            os = socket.getOutputStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[2^7-1];
                            int bytesRead = 0;
                            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer))!= -1) {
                                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                            os.close();
                            fis.close();
                        } else {
                            outputToClient.print("Status 400\r\n"
                                    + "File " + filename + " not found\r\n"
                                    + "\r\n");
                            outputToClient.flush();
                        }
                    }
                    outputToClient.flush();
                }
                           .................
                           .................
```

ClientSide:

```
       ............
                 ............
                if (request.startsWith("GET")) {
                File file = new File(request.substring(4));
                is = socket.getInputStream();
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                int bytesReceived = 0;

                while ((bytesReceived = is.read(buffer)) >=0) {
                    //while ((bytesReceived = is.read(buffer))>=buffer) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
                }
                request = "";
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            }
               .................
               .................
```

Comment: Reinventing the wheel? Better place to ask might be at codereview.

Comment: johnnnnn,  what     ?

Comment: Question should be asked the [stack review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @john [It already is.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/90818/52915)

Comment: @Mast so this is a duplicate. Ok, will flag.

Comment: @john If you must flag, flag it as cross-post. It's technically not a duplicate because it has no answer there yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me what you are asking, but as john pointed out- why dont you just take existing solutions like jetty server and adjust it to your taste?
To give an answer: HTTP status codes are missing for example.
And directly "map" to the server file system isn't best practice.

Comment: mayo, thank you very much. I guess you got my point. Can you please give me some more suggestion, can you show me specifically in the coding, where the status code is missing and what is the better way to map. Please. I will accept your answer and give you more upvote for each and every answer you post on this forum.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol and section "Example session". Every client request consists at least of that minimal example given in the article. Important response header fields are status (first line of response), content-type (your browser needs to know what type of data encoding is coming) and connection. The rest is up to you. To the file mapping issue: you need to understand that it is possible to request a file by GET /foo.html HTTP/1.1, but the server might response with the local stored file bar.html. By that you hide the real file structure.